# Nodemailer with sendmail plugin doesn't work

Tags: node.js, email, sendmail, nodemailer

As the title says, I want to send email in nodejs,Finally I choose [nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer) to send email. I use the [nodemailer-sendmail-transport](https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-sendmail-transport) to send email, here is my code:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var sendmailTransport = require('nodemailer-sendmail-transport');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(sendmailTransport())

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'fudy@test.com',
    to: 'fudy@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Hello ',
    text: 'Hello world',
    html: '<b>Hello world </b>'
};

 transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + JSON.stringify(info));
    console.log('error: ' + error);
    }
 );
```

and here is the result:

```
Message sent: {"envelope":{"from":"fudy@test.com","to":["fudy@gmail.com"]},"messageId":"1453216462751-f02d6225-98d2770f-68897c84@test.com"}
error: null
```

However, I haven't receive any email from fudy@test.com. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201601221424994/email-composer-send-emails-with-nodejs-and-mailgun

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your transport object.

`var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(options[, defaults]);`

Pass your parameters in for the type of transport method you would like to send the mail as. The options that are passable can be found on the nodemailer github you provided.

Comment: No, I don't need to configure options, there is default setting, I found that I can receive email only in my domain

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that sendmail program in my mac os only send email to the same domain. It can not send email to remote email address by default. But I think the plugin should give an error message.

Comment: I have same issue. Have you find any solution to send email into other domain? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45256114/nodemailer-mail-is-not-delivered-into-other-domain-like-gmail-yahoo/45256273#45256273)