# nodemailer mail is not delivered into other domain like gmail, yahoo

Tags: node.js, smtp, office365, nodemailer

NodeJS with nodemailer mail is not delivered into other domain like gmail, yahoo from my company domain.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'smtp.office365.com',
port: 587,
requireTLS: true,
tls: {
       ciphers: 'SSLv3'
   },
secureConnection: false, // use SSL
auth: {
  user: "XXX",// Your email id
  pass: "XXX"// Your password
},
debug: true
});
```

NodeJS v7.2.0
nodemailer v2.6.4

I am able to deliver mail into same domain network. Other domain not even getting any error and mail is not delivered.

```
Message sent: 250 2.6.0 <b831fb74-3585-4123-f519-9af2244e2dfe@yyy> [InternalId=49877455208613, Hostname=KL1PR02MB1512.apcprd02.prod.outlook.com] 13148 bytes in 0.592, 21.665 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery
```

Any idea for configuration?

Answer (score 0):

All it is doing is logging in remotely to send the email so if it sends it to same domain emails then it should send to all. I had a similar issue with a user and the email ended up being in the users spam.

Are you able to send emails to other domains when you access the email yourself?

If so..... you should try using a gmail to send it and see if that fixes anything so we can narrow down if the issue is nodemailer or your email.

Best of luck.

Comment: I have already tried with gmail. I am able to send it using `'host':'smtp.gmail.com',
'port':'465',
'service': 'Gmail'` But with my private domain with smtp.office365.com not able to sent.

Comment: also with python script similar configuration i am able to send email: `server = SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
            server.starttls()
            server.ehlo()
            server.login('eidevopsassessment@xxx.com', 'yyy')
            text = msg.as_string()
            server.sendmail('xxx.yyy@xxx.com', 'abc@gmail.com', text)
            server.quit()`

Comment: i am facing this issue, any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Using `name` property in the `transporter` configuration, works well for the gmail accounts (if you do not see the email in the inbox, check out the spam folder, you'll see it). For your config, add `name` property like this:

```
 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({

    name: "www.office365.com", <----------------- //just an example

    host: 'smtp.office365.com',
    port: 587,
    requireTLS: true,
    tls: {
      ciphers: 'SSLv3'
    },
      secureConnection: false, // use SSL
      auth: {
      user: "XXX",// Your email id
      pass: "XXX"// Your password
   },
   debug: true
 });
```

this config works for the gmail accounts, but not for yahoo accounts.

My yahoo account at first received 10 emails, then stopped receiving my emails sending with `nodemailer` with no error and even no spam. I just solved this issue by sending an email (a test email) from my gmail to my yahoo mail, when I received this email in my yahoo inbox, I could again send email via `nodemailer` to my yahoo mail.

I really don't know the reason, maybe yahoo had locked my email address because of sending 10 emails one after another in a small interval, and unlocked it when it received an email from another mail service.

I hope this help you too.